# Binary Search Algorithm Testing Repeated Values

Tags: python, algorithm

The python code below seems to work fine. If I change the code as per the comments, it still seems to work. Are there conditions where the algorithm will fail if I use `high = middle` instead of `high = middle - 1` and `low = middle` instead of `low = middle + 1`?

```
haystack = [3,5,7,8,9,23,65,89,100]
needle = 89
low = 0
high = len(haystack)

while (low < high):
  middle = (high + low)//2
  if (needle < haystack[middle] ):
     high = middle - 1 # what about just high = middle?
  elif (needle > haystack[middle]):
    low = middle + 1 # what about just low = middle?
  elif (needle == haystack[middle]):
    print ("The needle was found at index " + str (middle))
    break
```

Comment: since `middle` is already checked for, why would again assign `middle` to `low` or `high`?

Comment: your posted code isn't well aligned i guess?, im not sure: i dont think it will fail but slower

Comment: @Robin your current code doesn't work for `3`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are considering only on cases where the value is in the list (Maybe there is a case where the list contains the element and these lines are needed but i couldn't think of one)
think of the following simple case:

```
haystack = [1,2]
needle = 3
the rest of the code...
```

you will be stuck in an infinite loop without the current version of the code.

Note: as @vivek_23 mentioned you are already checking middle so there is no need for that extra iteration.

Comment: I get that I have already checked `middle` - I;m just wondering about if/when this could break the algorithm. I'm not concerned about efficiency so much.

Comment: Could you please explain why the infinite loop?

Comment: middle = (high + low)//2 --> middle =1 --> needle > haystack[middle]  --> low = 1 --> low < high --> ....

Answer (score 0):

In order for the loop to complete, each iteration must decrease the range by at least 1. If it doesn't you get an infinite loop.

If you ever reach a point where `low` is an even number and `high = low+1`, the calculation for `middle` will always return `low`. You will continually test the same location.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation as to why you would enter an infinite loop has to do with your condition:

```
while (low < high):
```

Not updating the conditions (low or high) would mean that your loop condition does not change and `low` (if it begins lower than high) will forever be less than `high`.

Another note is, it would help (you) to break code up into functions. It will make the debugging process easier for you in the future. Here's a not-so-pythonic implementation:

```
def binary_search(sorted_list, target_value, low, high):
    if (low > high):
        return False
    mid = (low + high) // 2

    if (mid == 0 and sorted_list[mid] != target_value):
        return False
    if sorted_list[mid] == target_value:
        return True
    elif sorted_list[mid] < target_value:
        return binary_search(sorted_list, target_value, mid + 1, high)
    else:
        return binary_search(sorted_list, target_value, low, mid)
```

If you want to ensure you can reach every item in a list, try testing if your algorithm finds everything in the list:

```
sorted_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9]
not_in_list = 42


def test_binary_search(sorted_list):
    for each_item in sorted_list:
        found = binary_search(sorted_list, each_item, 0, len(sorted_list) - 1)
        if not found:
            print("{} not found by binary_search".format(each_item))
        else:
            print("found {} ".format(each_item))


test_binary_search(sorted_list)
```

Similarly, you'd like your algorithm to behave correctly when given an item that is not in your list.

```
def test_item_not_found(sorted_list, item):
    expected = False
    actual = binary_search(sorted_list, item, 0, len(sorted_list) - 1)
    status = "Passed" if actual == expected else "Failed"
    print("status {} expected: {}, actual: {}".format(status, expected, actual))


test_item_not_found(sorted_list, not_in_list)
```